# Bootstrap popover js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-popover

Can anyone tell me how to add bootstrap-popover to my assets. Is it a separate plugin or it comes with bootstrap?
I add `//= require bootstrap-popover` to my application.js but getting below error

```
couldn't find file 'bootstrap-popover'
```

below is my current gemfile and application.js

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.12'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'honeybadger'
gem 'slim'
gem 'sorcery'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'resque'
gem 'resque-honeybadger'
gem 'resque_mailer'
gem 'moped'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'carmen-rails'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'browser'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'faraday', '0.8.8'
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'progress_bar'
gem 'coderay'
gem 'rubystats'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', '3.0.6'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'yui-compressor'
gem 'eco'
gem 'ejs'
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
gem 's3_direct_upload'
gem 'request_store'

//
//= require modernizr
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require honeybadger
//= require honeybadger.config
//= require jquery.timeago
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require jquery.ui.sortable
//= require jquery.ui.slider
//= require jquery.ui.progressbar
//= require jquery.polartimer
//= require jquery.mousewheel
//= require jquery.form.min
//= require jquery.csv-0.71.min
//= require underscore
//= require highcharts
//= require underscore.string.min
//= require backbone
//= require backbone-relational
//= require kinetic
//= require TweenLite
//= require raphael-min
//= require showdown
//= require srcset.min
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require twitter/typeahead.min
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require tagmanager
//= require bootstrap-popover
//= require prettyfile
//= require general
//= require samahub3
//= require environment
//= require SortedList
//= require s3_direct_upload
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ./mixins
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree .
```